# changing color using javascript

Tags: javascript

i am a beginner to java script.i do the bellow code for changing the text color into red using java script.But it doesn't work.what is the error in my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function display()
{
var col=document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
col.style.color="red";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>
<p id="demo">click on the button bellow.....</p>

<button onclick="display()">Display</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove `innerHTML` from `var col=document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function display()
{
var col=document.getElementById("demo");
col.style.color="#FF0000";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>
<p id="demo">click on the button below.....</p>

<button onclick="display()">Display</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

Dont use the `innerHTML`, it returns a String.

Use the style on the object itself.

Check out it working: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H4mZn/)

Comment: just use:
 
function display()
{
var col=document.getElementById("demo");
col.style.color="red";
}

Answer (score 3):

You can try this ...

```
document.getElementById('demo').style.color = '#FF0000';
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this code:

```
function display()
{
var col=document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
col.style.color="red";
}
```

with this:

```
function display()
{
var col=document.getElementById("demo");
col.style.color="red";
}
```

Inner html would contain the html inside the demo tag, but you need to refer to the tag itself.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function display()
{
document.getElementById("demo").style.color="red";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Your Fixed JavaScript</h1>
<p id="demo">click on the button bellow.....</p>

<button onclick="display()">Display</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the fixed one I just made the change of the words turn red because it wasn't