# How to change the font color of an user input value (prompt) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I change the color of the value of the variable number (`nb`)? How can I change the font color of an user input value (prompt) in JavaScript?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #block{
                color: white;
                width: 300px;
                height: 60px;
                background-color: #2b2e2e;
                text-align: center;
                padding-top: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="block">
            
        </div>
        <script>
            window.onload = function printNumber(){
                var unBlock = document.getElementById("block");
                var nb = Number(prompt("Saisir un nombre: "));
                
                if(nb == null || nb == ""){
                    unBlock.innerHTML = "No input number.";
                }else{
                    unBlock.innerHTML = "Your input number is "+nb;
                }
                
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried this example, that didn't work: nb.style.color = "blue";

Comment: The reason `nb.style.color = "blue";` doesn't work is because `nb` is just a variable representing the number that was entered. It does not control the HTML element where your `nb` will be rendered.

Comment: How does the number entered correspond to the color?

Comment: You can't change the color of anything in the dialog created as a result of the `prompt` command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [changing color using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575616/changing-color-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below illustrates two ways.

1. By creating a span with `colored` as its class, it turns it blue.
2. Subsequently, in my code, I'm overriding that by turning it red using javascript.

Either of those methods will work, but you only need one, not both.  I used both just for illustration of your options.

```js
window.onload = function printNumber() {
  var unBlock = document.getElementById("block");
  var nb = Number(prompt("Saisir un nombre: "));

  if (nb == null || nb == "") {
    unBlock.innerHTML = "No input number.";
  } else {
    unBlock.innerHTML = `Your input number is <span class='colored'>${nb}</span>`;
    //the next line will select your span and override blue with red.
    document.querySelector("span.colored").style.color = 'red';
  }

}
```

```css
#block {
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #2b2e2e;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

span.colored {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
</div>
```